# "Textfield validation not working properly"

Tags: java, netbeans

problem in validation part,  no message display about the empty field. help  immediately

private void addbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    try{

    Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbfinance","root","1234");
    String sql="insert into util(type_,due_date,month_,amount,units,status_) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pstm =con.prepareStatement(sql);

    pstm.setString(1,electype.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pstm.setString(2,date.getText().toString());
    pstm.setString(3,jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
    pstm.setDouble(4,Double.parseDouble(amount.getText()));
    pstm.setString(5,unit.getText());
    pstm.setString(6,status.getText());



   pstm.executeUpdate();
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success");
   con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

        }
     if(amount.getText().isEmpty()||unit.getText().isEmpty()||status.getText().isEmpty()){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter data");

           // errorname2.setText("fill this field");
    }        
}
```

Comment: Which empty field are you talking about? Given the limited info you have shared we cannot even reproduce the problem you're facing and hence to find a solution for that.

Comment: in this program amount text field ,unit text field and status text field should not be empty(user should  fill that fields ) .if it is empty ,should display message "please enter data".but the problem is that message doesn't display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be inserting the data in to the database before validating. Only insert the data if they are not empty. As for checking whether the data is empty or not, it would be better if you trim the text so that any empty spaces will get trimmed out given white spaces denotes some value.

```
if(amount.getText().trim().isEmpty()||unit.getText().trim().isEmpty()||
            status.getText().trim().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter data");
        // errorname2.setText("fill this field");
    }
```

Please make sure that you are inserting the trimmed data in to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Try to validate your amount field if it's empty before applying `try-catch` statement:

```
if(amount.getText().isEmpty()||unit.getText().isEmpty()||status.getText().isEmpty()){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"please enter data");
        // errorname2.setText("fill this field");
    }else{
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbfinance","root","1234");
            String sql="insert into util(type_,due_date,month_,amount,units,status_) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement pstm =con.prepareStatement(sql);
            pstm.setString(1,electype.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pstm.setString(2,date.getText().toString());
            pstm.setString(3,jComboBox1.getSelectedItem().toString());
            pstm.setDouble(4,Double.parseDouble(amount.getText()));
            pstm.setString(5,unit.getText());
            pstm.setString(6,status.getText());
            pstm.executeUpdate();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "success");
            con.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: now it gives the message "java.lang.NumberFormatException:empty string".but need to display the message"please enter data".

Comment: Probably the `isEmpty()` method is not working propertly, try replacing it with `amount.getText().equals("")` for each field.

Comment: same issue .now it inserts data to database without input any value to the status text field.